# Why shouldn't bootstrap containers be nested?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I sometimes find myself wanting to place a full width background for one section of a site where the content is within a standard container.  Something like:

```
<div class="container">
  <!--here is a section of awesome things that doesn't need a full width background -->
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: purple">
  <div class="container>
    <p>This is an average paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap says NOT to nest containers](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container).

```
Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.
```

I understand that I can just make a different div with a class, but I wonder what the specific dangers of nesting containers may be?

Comment: you can use multiples but not nested. without considering the risks. The risks are that some things within bootstrap are reliant on relative selectors. these would perhaps break in the case of nesting. i have come across this with nesting various elements before.

Answer (score 1):

sorry couldnt explain in a comment, here's what I follow

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: purple">
    <div clas=row>
<!--here is a section of awesome things that doesn't need a full width background -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: purple">
    <div clas=row>
        <div class="container>
                <div class=row>
                <p>This is an average paragraph</p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: interesting o.0 nice.